# How to group by string ID in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by

How do I get :

```
ID                 Value
99-07-06-01          1
99-07-06-02          2
99-07-06             3

99-07-08-01          4
99-07-08-02          5
99-07-08             6

to

ID                  Value
99-07-06              6
99-07-08              15
```

i.e I wanted to group by the ID [99-07-0x] while summing.
thanks

Comment: How did you get C & F, as I can see value to be SUM?

Comment: Sorry, C & F should be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (both MySQL and MS-SQL):

```
SELECT LEFT(ID, 8) AS nID,
       SUM(Value) AS tot
FROM your_table
GROUP BY LEFT(ID, 8)
```

Comment: I was under the impression that you couldn't group by an alias in MS-SQL.. ?

Comment: @Gibron: there are also other constructs one can use: sub-query or use `GROUP BY LEFT(ID, 8)`

Comment: @Gibron: honestly I'm not sure, but I edited my post to reflect your suggestion. Thanks a lot :)